# Displaying one div below another

Tags: css

I'm clueless how to get the scrollbar display below the active box - list item.

After searching I have found that the z-index should work on element positioned other than static. But still I'm still unable to produce the desired effect.

This is just one part of my problem, I believe if I understand the solution to this one, I can also fix another similar problem.

Somehow the active box is displayed on top of the scrollbar, but not the scrollbar's handle.

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hBT4/). Should be quite easy to notice my problem.

The desired effect is that the scrollbar and everything related to it (handle) is displayed below the active(longer, red) box.

```
Sorry, don't really see a way to accompany this problem with code inside the post or how to make the JsFiddle with less code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to apply a z-index to the `.scrollbar` element itself, rather than its child `.scroller`. Add these styles to your definition of it:

```
.scrollbar {
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}
```

And you should get (what I hope is) your desired behaviour. Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hBT4/2/) for you to see what this achieves. If this isn't what you were looking for, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: So the problem was just assigning z-index to correct elements. I see now. And yes this was the desired behavior. Any special reason to adding line-height: 0? Seems to work the same without it?

Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help out! The `z-index` property is one that doesn't always behave as expected. And regarding the `line-height`...ah, see your original JSFiddle - that was already there. (I also don't know why, though.)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Somehow missed it when compared the before and after. Thanks for the help. Will try to play with z-index more with the other similar problem.

Comment: Are you sure that position:relative; wouldn't create a problem with scrolling?

Comment: Just FYI, it has messed up the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: @Learner Having tested this in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome, (wrapped in the JSFiddle) I can't say I've seen some kind of undefined behaviour. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Wow, I see the scroll-bar direction is reversed now.

Comment: Ah...yeah, the scroller's intended behaviour is to move in the direction you're scrolling, opposite to the direction the content is moving. (If that's what you're seeing.)